# Count column in row if condition matched

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE table
    a character varying(255),
    b character varying(255),
    c character varying(255),
    d character varying(255)
);


column | value
-------+------
a      | "Correct"
b      | "Correct"
c      | "Incorrect"
d      | "Something Else"
-------+------
correct| 2
```

How could I calculate "correct" as the count of other columns in the same row that meet the criteria of containing the string "Correct"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is rather brute force:

```
select t.*,
       ( (a = 'Correct')::int + (b = 'Correct')::int + 
         (c = 'Correct')::int + (d = 'Correct')::int
       ) as num_correct
from t;
```

A more fun method uses a lateral join:

```
select t.*, v.num_correct
from t left join lateral
     (select count(*) as num_correct
      from (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) v(x)
      where x = 'Correct'
     ) v
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the nearly instant answer!

Comment: Never seen a lateral join before.  But it works.  :-)